# Is PHP Connector a part of DHTMLX Scheduler

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

I am trying to use DHTMLX Scheduler to load data from MySQL on the server. I am not clear is PHP Connector is included as part of DHTMLX Scheduler or is it a separate download and install?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dhtmlxConnector and dhtmlxScheduler are separate libraries/components -  the former is backend library to connect any dhtmlx component to the database and the later is client-side only calendar/scheduler component which can be used with or without dhtmlx connector.

PHP version of dhtmlx connector is included in download package of dhtmxl scheduler, i.e. if you download free version of scheduler from here https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/download.shtml  - you can find php connectors in package/codebase/connector, package samples uses them.
Any other connector packages (.NET and Java) must be downloaded separately if needed.

Comment: Thank you @AlexKlimenkov. That is what I gathered, but was not exactly sure. Their documentation is comprehensive, but in most cases it falls short of being crystal clear on anything highly technical and it is not well organized.

Comment: I feel your pain:) feel free to open issue/pull request in public repo of documentation site  https://github.com/DHTMLX/scheduler-docs if you'll have suggestions or if you notice something particularly outrageous, we'll see it and will try to react (FYI i work for dhtmlx). 
you can find raw docs files in /data folder. 
though as for now, only scheduler and gantt have public repositories for documentation, dhtmlxsuite and connector docs have none.

Comment: Thanks AlexKlimenkov. I actually installed both the Gantt plugin and the Scheduler plugin. Both are very handy on my web app project. Gantt was a piece of cake to install, acclimate too, and implement in production. Scheduler on the other hand...well, it has been a battle. The plugin seems so comprehensive, yet so complex. Like I stated, the documentation is very comprehensive but overwhelming and not fully fleshed out. I am most likely planning on getting the PRO version of Scheduler because I really want  the Timeline feature. Before I spent that money though, I wanted to see: <cont>

Comment: (a) how easy it is install and configure Scheduler, and (b) how well supported the free version is from the community, etc. Support and forum answers have been pretty good from Polina and from Aliaksandr. Turnaround has been 1-3 days if overlapping the weekend. But the configuration part is a slight up-hill battle... Thanks again @AlexKlimenkov